# how to search or find a particular substring in a list

Tags: python, list

```
value = ["python:guru-age20",
         "is_it_possible_time100:goodTime99",
         "hmm_hope_no_onecanansswer"]
```

How to get a particular string from this list of strings? I need to find `goodTime99` from the `li[1]` string and its exact postion

`if value.find("goodTime99") != -1:` I know will work if I give the entire string `is_it_possible_time100:goodTime99`.

Otherwise how to exact the position by searching `goodTime99` instead of searching for `is_it_possible_time100:goodTime99`?  `value.index("goodTime99")` is giving an error.

I am not looking for whole string to search, `value.index("is_it_possible_time100:goodTime99")` is fine but I don't want this. Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to check for the presence of `"goodTime99"` in any string in the list, you could try:

```
value = ["python:guru-age20", "is_it_possible_time100:goodTime99","hmm_hope_no_onecanansswer"]
if any("goodTime99" in s for s in value):
    # found it
```

If you need the exact position:

```
>>> next((i for i, s in enumerate(value) if "goodTime991" in s), -1)
1
```

or:

```
def find_first_substring(lst, substring):
    return next((i for i, s in enumerate(lst) if substring in s), -1)

>>> find_first_substring(value, "goodTime99")
1
```

Comment: This is fine but i need the exact postion of the stirng li[0] or li[1]

Comment: oot@sr-query:/# python volume_check.py new_volume
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "volume_check.py", line 23, in <module>
    next(i for i, s in enumerate(mount_list) if "goodTime99" in s)
StopIteration
root@sr-query:/#

Comment: Python 2.6.1  this is my version

Comment: @SRquery I've edited my question to avoid the `StopIteration`, I hope it's clearer now :)

Answer (score 2):

if you want a single line answer you can have

```
In [339]: [value.index(x) for x in value if x.find("goodTime99") > -1]
Out[339]: [1]
```

simplest way could be :

it will give you all the index's of the strings containing your substring from the list

```
In [334]: value = ["python:guru-age20",
   .....:          "is_it_possible_time100:goodTime99",
   .....:          "hmm_hope_no_onecanansswer"]

In [335]: indexs = []

In [336]: for x in value:
   .....:     if x.find("goodTime99") > -1:
   .....:         indexs.append(value.index(x))
   .....:

In [337]: print indexs
[1]

In [338]: int(*indexs)
Out[338]: 1
```

Comment: @SRquery: it is `indexs` not `index` ... copy paste the exact thing is python prompt, you will get the results... check the oneliner answer it will help you

Comment: @avasal, `[value.index(x) for x in value if x.find("goodTime99") > -1]
Out[339]: [1]`, this is not very efficient since you will search the index of x for every x that matches. It would be better to use enumerate to generate the index first.

Answer (score 1):

this will give you all the matches with also the indexes if you need:

```
filter(lambda x: x[1].find("goodTime99") != -1, enumerate(value))
```

if you want the indexes only, then

```
[e[0] for e in filter(lambda x: x[1].find("goodTime99") != -1, enumerate(value))]
```

for example, this is what I got:

```
>>> value = ["python:guru-age20", "is_it_possible_time100:goodTime99","hmm_hope_no_onecanansswer"]
>>> res = [e[0] for e in filter(lambda x: x[1].find("goodTime99") != -1, enumerate(value))]
>>> res
[1]
```

Comment: see: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter filter returns a list with matched elements.

Comment: @SRquery, have you tried this? if you write `res = filter(lambda x: x[1].find("goodTime99") != -1, enumerate(value))`, res will be **[(1, 'is_it_possible_time100:goodTime99')]** with your input above

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to search through each individual string in turn:

```
for s in value:
  if s.find("goodTime99"):
     print "found in", s
     break
```

Comment: `s.find` returns an integer value indicating the start of the match, with `-1` meaning not found. `-1` is a Truethy value, it'll thus always print "found" except if the string *starts* with `goodTime99`. You want to use an `in` test instead: `if "goodTime99" in s:`.